# Constant background color when using Matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, background-color

This may seem like an easy question but it is throwing me for a loop.  For a code I am working on, I'm using the matplotlib.image.imsave function to save images of bladders of very thicknesses.  The images are grayscale images that have a lower grayscale value for thicker regions and vice versa for thinner regions.  My problem is that using matplotlib function converts it into a color image, which is what I want, however, the background is not consistent from image to image.

I have attached to images to show you what I mean.  My question is, is it as simple as adding a `**kwargs` to the matplotlib function, say:

`matplotlib.image.imsave('thickness.png', image_array, **kwargs)`

where I can make the kwargs give me a constant blue background?

thick bladder with red highlighting very thick regions:
[image: thick bladder with red highlighting very thick regions]

thin bladder has a different background than the thick one:
[image: thin bladder has a different background than the thick one]

Comment: Could it be something to do with the range of greyscale values for your image? Ie. could the first figure have a larger range of values than the second.

Comment: That is a possibility. I was thinking that matplotlib wants to maximize the contrast it shows it this way. I tried to normalize the images in using from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize but since the range is so different I end up with the same images doing normalization and I can't think of a way to make their range the same.

Comment: did you try the `vmin/vmax` arguments? [imshow docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=imshow#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow)

Comment: You can add a [`colorbar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar) to the figure that shows you the color/value ranges. This should immediately clarify if the background colors are due to different ranges.

Comment: I tried the vmin/max argument and I could not get the background to be consistently one color.  The colorbar would tell me that but I already know from the grayscale that the background is consistently between 160-175 grayscale values but the grayvalue of the bladders are the only thing that changes from picture to picture.

Comment: if the backgound values are always around the same value, you should set `vmin=160` and `vmax` to some number greater than the maximum value in any of the bladders. is that what you did?

Comment: Yes I did do that from @Bonlenfum suggestion but their was still a difference in the background colors.  Except 'vmax = 160' and 'vmin = 100'

Comment: I think I'll play with the colormaps and the vmin and vmax some more.  I think the vmin and vmax wasn't working before because I did not clear the variables.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!  I have it sort of working now, a lot better looking than before!  I just have vmin and vmax not as fixed values but as variables based on the min and max from the array and then changed the color map to 'seismic.'

Comment: Don't forget that if you solved your problem, you can add your own answer!

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know I was aloud to do that, being a new user and all.  I will do that now!

Answer (score 0):

Using this gave me a more consistent background.  I used the vmin/vmax functions and played with the color maps.  My background is now more consistent.  Not the same color but at least the background for both images is a shade of blue, good enough for what I am doing.

```
thick = f + filtered_array
q = amax(thick)
o = amin(thick)
matplotlib.image.imsave('thickness.png', thick, vmin = o, vmax = q, cmap = 'seismic')
```

[image: Thin bladder]